# How to annotate and train data for predominantly numeric data extraction

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy, information-extraction, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract information from unstructured text. For example

> The CEO has recently sought suggestions for features to add to the truck under development and he revealed some planned features, like an option for 400 to 500 miles of range, Dual Motor All-wheel-drive powertrain with dynamic suspension, ‘300,000 lbs of towing capacity’, and more. When asked about the release date, the CEO gave an estimated time of Q2 2021.

Ideal output would be something like

```
[minRange = 400, maxRange = 500, allWheelDrive = TRUE, susepnsionType = 'Dynamic', releaseDate = 2021-04-01 00:00]
```

Because the data I want to extract won't always be structured in well-behaved pairs (e.g., the releaseDate extraction above requires semantically processing the entire sentence) regex and a few rules probably won't suffice. I believe I need to annotate my datasets and then use NLP and learning tools such as spaCy, NLTK, or Stanford NLP to extract the attribute-value pairs from future examples.

I am trying to use online resources / tutorials but they all seem to be focused on either named entity recognition alone or extracting relations on to string-based entities (e.g., LOC:Paris, REL:is capital of, LOC:France). Most (not all) of the data I need to extract is just attribute-numeric value pair. How do I accomplish this with NLP tools? For the most part I'm just not sure if the numbers should be considered entities, and if so, should they be annotated as an entity named "Value" or given an entity name with the associated attribute. For example, which of these two is the better way to annotate?:

1. The <\PRODUCT>vehicle<\PRODUCT> has a towing capacity of <\TOWING_CAP>300,000 lbs<\TOWING_CAP>
2. The <\PRODUCT>vehicle<\PRODUCT> has a towing capacity of <\VALUE>300,000 lbs<\VALUE>, RELATION:"has towing capacity"

Comment: Did you find a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you move forward with spaCy, I'd avoid trying to recognize numbers in the NER as they are already recognized in the parser's dependency tree as `QUANTITY`.

```
>>> import spacy
>>> text = "We have a towing capacity of 5,000 lbs"
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
>>> doc = nlp(text)
doc.print_tree()
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Positional arguments to Doc.merge are deprecated. Instead, use the keyword arguments, for example tag=, lemma= or ent_type=.
[{'word': 'have', 'lemma': 'have', 'NE': '', ...{'word': 'of', ... 'modifiers': [{'word': '5,000 lbs', 'lemma': '5,000 lbs', 'NE': 'QUANTITY', 'POS_fine': 'NNS', 'POS_coarse': 'NOUN', 'arc': 'pobj', 'modifiers': []}]}]}]}]
```

You can train the `ner` pipeline to pick up on new labels such as `PRODUCT`, though I'd highly recommend reading up on the [catastrophic forgetting](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting) problem, whereby the model will "forget" old labels as you hone in on new ones. I've personally encountered this with a coworker as we trained the ner to recognize `COMPANY` as a label.

What I might do is instead of training the NER to recognize each feature, I'd probably train it to recognize `FEATURE` as an entity, and then feed it things such as "All wheel drive" or "Offroad suspension", that way you can aggregate all of the `FEATURE`s from a piece of text, rather than training for each one. Of course, this depends on the end-game for what you want out of NLP. The only reason I'd suggest is that I'd imagine the number of possible options on a vehicle will grow and grow (for instance, would you include radar cruise as a feature in your ideal output?) and having a catch-all will make things a touch easier. Again, that depends on your end goal here

Comment: That makes sense as a starting point, thank you. Once I have that sorted out then I need to establish the relations to associate the QUANTITY (in most cases) with the FEATURE.